# How would you edit this so that the array is shifted 2 places? Ex. Final array is 30, 40,10, 20

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Want to shift the array by a DWORD variable of 2 so that the final array is 30,40,10,20

Want to support an array of variable length

```
.data
array DWORD 10,20,30,40
arrayType DWORD TYPE array
newArray DWORD LENGTHOF array DUP(?)
lastElement DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

;Get first element address in ESI
MOV ESI, OFFSET array

;Get address of next element in EDI
MOV EDI, OFFSET newArray
ADD EDI, TYPE newArray

;set loop count into ecx
mov ECX, LENGTHOF array

L2:
MOV EAX, [ESI]
MOV [EDI], EAX

ADD ESI, TYPE array
ADD EDI, TYPE array

LOOP L2

;set last element from array in newArray first position
MOV EDI,OFFSET newArray
MOV EAX, [ESI]
MOV [EDI], EAX
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing to a separate destination so there's no overlap between reading and writing.  That makes it pretty simple:  You loop from first to last of one array, and start in the middle of the other array with wrapping.

e.g. start from the first element of the destination, and use a branch to conditionally subtract the length (in bytes) from the src pointer.  (Branching is a good choice vs. cmov because it will only be true once; every other time you're just looping normally).

Or split up your loop to copy in 2 chunks: from the middle of the src to the end, then from the start to the middle.

You could even use `rep movsd` twice for this instead of loops, leaving `edi` unmodified to keep appending the destination, but resetting `esi` to read from the start of the source.  (If you're not going to use SIMD vectors, `rep movsd` is faster than a 4-byte-at-a-time copy loop for probably 10 elements or more.  Or with the the slow-on-Intel `loop` instruction, the break-even point is even lower.)

For the fixed-size problem, you can of course just load the whole thing into 4 registers, or use SSE2 `movdqu`-load / `pshufd` / `movdqu`-store to shuffle dword chunks of a 16 byte SIMD vector.

---

If you had to do this rotate in-place (updating one array instead of making a modified copy), you could hardcode the "rotate by 2 positions" part over variable length using a couple scratch registers to handle the overlap between writing and reading.

---

I'm not going to post code because this looks like homework and I couldn't show an example without just solving it.

But `arrayType DWORD TYPE array` looks like a bad idea.  `TYPE array` is an assemble-time constant; you don't want to store it in memory and load it as data, just use it as an immediate like you're doing with `ADD ESI, TYPE array`

`lastElement DWORD ?` is also unused, and again that's a good thing.  Use registers (until your run out) for single-dword chunks of scratch space.